# How to make NFC Tag writable only by my app?

Tags: android, ios, nfc

I am trying to make NFC Writer app which will write URL links. I want to restrict my users from using third party apps on my NFC Tags, so my question is how do I make NFC Tags writeable only using my app?

Comment: If you have a writable tag, anyone can write on it, an application cannot prevent that.

Comment: While the suggested duplicate answer does partly answer the question for one of the many different Tag makes and model and for iOS only and does not cover the Android Tag, this question should not have been closed as a duplicate, it should have been closed as "Needs detail or clarity" as password protection is specific to the make and model of the Tag which is not specified in the question.